# iOS 6.0: UISplitViewController Popover broken or design changed by Apple?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, ios6, uipopovercontroller

I have created a project with master detail template in Xcode 4.5 and deployment target 5.1. Could someone please help me with following UISplitViewController issues please.

1. In portrait mode, master view fade in from the left. It doesn't appear as Popover view as it used in iOS 5.0 in portrait mode. Please see attached images. How to get the master view as popover?
2. Is there anyway I can hide master view in Landscap mode?

Thanks.[image: popover in ios 6.0]

[image: popover till ios 5.0]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been the default action since 5.1.
From the iOS 6 release notes:

> In iOS 5.1, the UISplitViewController class adopts the sliding
>   presentation style when presenting the left view (previously seen only
>   in Mail). This style is used when presentation is initiated either by
>   the existing bar button item provided by the delegate methods or by a
>   swipe gesture within the right view. No additional API adoption is
>   required to obtain this behavior, and all existing APIs—including that
>   of the UIPopoverController instance provided by the delegate—will
>   continue to work as before.
>
> If the gesture would be insupportable in your app, setting the
>   presentsWithGesture property of your split view controller to NO
>   disables the gesture. However, disabling the gesture is discouraged
>   because its use preserves a consistent user experience across all
>   apps.

There's a [dirty way](http://www.i4-apps.com/splitviewcontroller-popovers/) to fix this.

Comment: hi. i want to add leftside one tableview and right side tableview. When i click the left tableview i want to show another tableview in right side tableview how can i do this.

Comment: You will need to implement your custom splitview controller! Have a look at https://github.com/masaniparesh/MGSplitViewController and discussions. It partially does what you looking for. Good luck.