# How to update the dimensions of the "Master" UIPopoverController in the Master/Detail Template

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller, master-detail

I have a project that is built using the Master/Detail template for the iPad.  When it was developed using iOS 5.0, it was easy to update the popoverview by just adjusting the view controller inside the popover by doing (ex):

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = GCRect(500.0, 500.0)
```

This would take the default popoverview that is displayed and make it much wider, so that I could fit more content on the screen on less rows.

However, once I checked on iOS 6, I noticed that the actual popoverview is completely different, and looks more like a "slider-over" view, as once you click the button at the top, the popoverview now slides over from the left hand side to the right and the size isn't updated anymore.  What do I need to do to get this "slider" to be wider?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670300/ios-6-0-uisplitviewcontroller-popover-broken-or-design-changed-by-apple

Comment: @jrturton - While the post you gave mentions the change from the popoverview to a "slide" view, I didn't see any mention of changing the size of the new "slide" view.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't resize UISplitViewController's views.. Consider using some third party components or make your own in order to implement desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hack the default UISplitViewController. I've been pretty far in this, but you'll end up with unexpected assertions.

If getting it wider is really what you want, you must consider using MGSplitViewController : https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController

It offers the ability to set the width of the master through the following method:

`- (void)setSplitPosition:(float)posn animated:(BOOL)animate;`